# Какую строку подключения для DbContext стоит использоавть для удаленной PostgreSQL базы данных для npgsql?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net, entity-framework, npgsql

День добрый. Пишу приложение под ASP.NET. Хочу подключиться к удаленной базе PG, с использованием EF Core. Какую строку подключения необходимо использовать, при условии того, что для подключения к серверу необходим SSH-ключ?

Я спокойно подключился к удаленной БД через pgAdmin т.к. там можно указать файл ключа и пароль к нему (что является подтверждением, что проблем на стороне сервера нет). В случае со строкой подключения, исходя из документации, указать SSH-файл напрямую нет возможности.

Вот как выглядит строка сейчас "Host=АЙПИ_СЕРВЕРА;Port=5432;Database=ИМЯ_БД; Username=ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ_БД;Password=ПАРОЛЬ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ;"

При попытке достучаться до бд ловлю таймаут.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58219681/5045688